# An application is listening on ports 139 and 445, but those ports are closed. Can an application listen on closed ports?

Tags: networking

On the terminal, when using `netstat`, it claims a program called `smbd` (which is actually Samba) is listening on ports 139 and 445, but according to a port scan from ShieldsUp, those ports are closed.

Exactly how is an application listening to ports that are closed?

Comment: @user68186 So only devices in my LAN have access to those ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a direct internet connection but are using a router that gives you a private IP address ShieldsUp doesn't actually scan your computer but your router. It's unlikely that your router is listening on those ports unless it is forwarding them.

If you have a direct internet connection but a package filter on your computer (`iptables`) or somewhere between your computer and ShieldsUp filters packages for port 139 and 445 ShieldsUp will report this ports as closed even if `smbd` is listening on them.